# How to return nil when no image is present in paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have one model that is

```
class Retailer < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
    has_attached_file :onboarding_image
  ...
end
```

If the onboarding_image is not present, when doing `retailer.onboarding_image_url` i'm getting: "/onboarding_images/original/missing.png"

Is there a config to get `nil` when no image is present? i know that i can do something like

`retailer.onboarding_image.present? ? retailer.onboarding_image : nil` but that is not the approach i want to follow, cause i have thousand of attached_files in all of my code.

Comment: Looks like its reported issue, but as paperclip is deprecated, this wont be fixed( 
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/2345

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `default_url` as outlined [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#models):

```
 has_attached_file :onboarding_image, default_url: ''
```

Another approach is to override the `onboarding_image_url` method:

```
  def onboarding_image_url(default_value=nil)
    onboarding_image.present? ? onboarding_image.url : default_value
  end
```

Comment: yes! i've tried that before, but nil is the value i want to fetch, and not an empty string

Comment: cause if the image is not present, the most consistent value to get is nil

Comment: @LucasJuarez passing `nil` to `default_url` raises an exception. I added another solution

Answer (score 0):

if you have this attached files on multiple models, you can create concern for all classes that have `has_attached_file` :

```
module BoardUrl
  def board_url
    onboarding_image.present? ? onboarding_image.url : nil
  end
end
```

```
class Retailer
  include BoardUrl
end
```

This way you can use your `board_url` method on any model you need.

Comment: good, i know these kind of approaches, the idea is to make it with some configuration, imagine that i have ten of has_attached_file in one model, and i have like 20 models with attached files. So, the idea is not to create new methods to check these things but make it with some config

Comment: @LucasJuarez I get it.. that's another question as well, but you can do smthg with meta programming where you would define dynamic methods that would be created in run time whenever you need some check. You can put it in this concern and include wherever you need